# How to create a list of all built-in PHP functions a project makes use of?

Tags: php

Background: PHP allows providers to disable functions (directive "disable_functions"). So in order to get to know if your project is running on a specific server you'll have to check:

1. What built-in (=excluding user-defined) functions is your to-be-deployed project using?
2. Are the functions available on the specific host?

(Question (2) is a trivial loop over the result (1) with `function_exists`.)

In order to get the harvesting working (=a mostly complete set of built-in functions used on the development servers) one could create a list of functions with `get_loaded_extensions()`, `get_extension_funcs()` and `get_defined_functions()` (and access it's 'internal' array for the built-in functions).

Now the question: How would you extract/grep the built-in PHP functions used in the project from your (possibly hundreds of) source files?

It could be a nice PERL job or somethig like that. How would you do it?

Comment: Not to forget: A possible parser must ignore mere mentions of a function in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP tokenizer - namely [**token_get_all()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) - is probably the most reliable tool for this, as it uses the same parsing mechanism the PHP interpreter itself does.

If you're looking for a Perl based solution, [**phpxref**](http://phpxref.sourceforge.net/faq.php) has a function to tell all used built in functions: Random example [**here**](http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?_functions/index.html#php).